# how to make triangle div?

Tags: html, css

I want to make div like triangle. I describe clear my question by images in blow.

my code is:

```
<div class="rest_pack">
                        <img width="100%" src="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . '/files/upload/3.png' ?>">
                        <div class="row side_info">
                            <div class="top">
                                ساندویچ مخصوص
                            </div>
                            <div class="bottom">
                                5,500 
                                تومان
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

css:

```
.rest_pack .side_info{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    top: 100px;
    opacity: 0.8;

}
.rest_pack .side_info .top{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #3131AA;
    padding-top:5px;
}
.rest_pack .side_info .bottom{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #F63440;
    padding-top:5px;
}
```

The result is:
[image]

but I want something like this.
I want to make red DIV.

[image]

Comment: Could you show us your code as well?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That desired effect has nothing whatsoever to do with border-radius. If you want to generate it using CSS, then reseach _CSS triangles_.

Comment: please make an example

Comment: You mean I have to use effect for borders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `:after` selector and `border-left`, `border-bottom` to adjust triangle as you need.

like this:

```css
.title{
  position: absolute;
  padding:25px;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:1;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys1Jo.png");
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 500px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 130px solid rgb(0, 114, 255);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.999);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <span class="title">Enter Text Here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please vote may question? I'm question ban :-(

Answer (score 2):

Got it from CSS Tricks https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

```
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

CSS goes here :

```
.arrow-up {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;

border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.arrow-down {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 20px solid transparent;
border-right: 20px solid transparent;

border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

.arrow-right {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 60px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-left {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-top: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 

border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
```

Just change values and you get whatever Triangle you want

Comment: yes it is useful too, do you know why somebody vote for my question fornegetive?

Comment: could you please vote may question? I'm question ban :-(

Comment: yeah, next time try to follow the rules and ask questions more precisely (with some code in it)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

HTML

```
<div class="main">
  <a rel="nofollow" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys1Jo.png"><img alt="enter image description here" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys1Jo.png">   </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main {  border: 1px solid red; border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px; }
```

Comment: I mean is not round border